# parseRequest() in Filter returns ActionForm as blank

Tags: java, filter, struts-1, apache-commons-fileupload

I've added a filter in my Struts 1.2 application which is triggered before the request is taken to the ActionForm. I've got a multipart/form-data in my jsp so I use apache.commons.FileUpload to parse the request and get my specific request parameter by using the parseRequest(HttpServletRequest)-method of ServletFileUpload class.

After the processing is done and the request is passed to the actionForm, there is no data in my Form. I know that a request can only be parsed once and since i am already parsing it in my filter, i am not getting data in my Form.

Is there any alternate way by which data is available in the form even after parsing the request in the filter.

This is the code that i have used in my filter

```
List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(servletRequest);
            for (FileItem item : multiparts) {

                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    String name = item.getFieldName();
                    stripXSS(item.getString());  
                }
            }
```

The other code that i tried is:

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(servletRequest);
            while(iterator.hasNext()){


                FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                if(item.isFormField()){
                    String name = item.getFieldName();
                    String value = Streams.asString(stream);             
                    stripXSS(item.getString());
                }
            }
```

But this also gave the same issue.